# 2 letter value in search not working magento 2.3

Tags: magento2

Hello Magento Experts,

I have an issue with the search functionality. My website have products as HP Laptops. And here are the three-issue I faced.

1. If user type HP then result not showing. The 2 letters search not working.
2. If I type the SKU like HTIC-12JOL-IJMSF4 then also not work.
3. If the product name is long or product name with some numbers not work.

Can you please help me step by step solution of each task?

Thank you in advance folks!

Comment: Are you able to solve search product name with number?
i am also getting this isssue

Comment: @sumeetbajaj hi did you find any solution for this i am also facing same issue

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Go to Catalog --> Catalog Search 
In the Minimal Query Length field
In the Maximum Query Length field
Update field as per requirement.

Comment: I did it already and it's not working.

Comment: @NileshPatel hi did you find any solution for this i am also facing same issue